# How to get these images to fall down the screen with a set .y and a random .x

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

[image: the apple fall should look somthing like this:]

How to get these images to fall down the screen with a set .y and a random .x, and get these images to regenerate when smallapple1 hits the middle of the screen?

(i want the apples to have a litte gap, thats why .y needs to be a specific number)

`IBOutlet UIImageView *smallapple1;`
`IBOutlet UIImageView *smallapple2;`
`IBOutlet UIImageView *smallapple3;`
`IBOutlet UIImageView *smallapple4;`

ive seen some similar questions but the answers have not fitted my current question ;)

I've tried this code but to many apples where generated, my character was laggy, and the apples spawned into each other. someone who can fix this code?

```
-(void)dispatchSomeRaindrops
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallapple.jpg"]];

        CGFloat halfHeight = view.frame.size.height / 2;
        CGFloat x = arc4random() % (int)self.view.frame.size.width;
        view.center = CGPointMake(x, -halfHeight);

        [self.view addSubview:view];

        NSTimeInterval duration = 5 + arc4random() % 10;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            float endY = self.view.frame.size.height + halfHeight;
            view.center = CGPointMake(x, endY);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }
}
```

(found this code from a similar question here on Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is awfully open-ended, and kind of a "please show me how to solve this elaborate problem. I'm not going to give you the whole answer, but I'll start you in the right direction:

The easiest way to do this would be to use UIView animation. Take a look at the method `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`

You probably want the option for a linear animation.

You'd pass code into the completion block that would trigger another animation.

Do you want smallApple1 to stop at the middle of the screen, or are you saying that you want more images to appear when smallApple1 gets to the middle of the screen but then smallApple1 continues it's progress down the screen?

I will take a little work to come up with the logic to do what you want, but that method should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Duncan! I want more images to appear when smallApple1 gets to the middle of the screen but then smallApple1 continues it's progress down the screen.

Comment: To do that you'll have to calculate how long it will take for your apple view to reach the middle of the screen, then use a method like performSelector:withObject:afterDelay to queue up new objects after the appropriate delay.